# Check if string is exactly the same as line in file

Tags: python

I've been writing a Countdown program in Python, and in it. I've written this:

```
#Letters Game

global vowels, consonants
from random import choice, uniform
from time import sleep
from itertools import permutations

startLetter = ""
words = []

def check(word, startLetter):
    fileName = startLetter + ".txt"
    datafile = open(fileName)
    for line in datafile:
        print("Checking if", word, "is", line.lower())
        if word == line.lower():
            return True
    return False

def generateLetters():
    lettersLeft = 9
    output = []
    while lettersLeft >= 1:
        lType = input("Vowel or consonant? (v/c)")
        sleep(uniform(0.5, 1.5))
        if lType not in ("v", "c"):
            print("Please input v or c")
            continue
        elif lType == "v":
            letter = choice(vowels)
            print("Rachel has picked an", letter)
            vowels.remove(letter)
            output.append(letter)
        elif lType == "c":
            letter = choice(consonants)
            print("Rachel has picked a", letter)
            consonants.remove(letter)
            output.append(letter)

        print("Letters so far:", output)
        lettersLeft -= 1

    return output

def possibleWords(letters, words):
    for i in range(1,9):
        print(letters)
        print(i)
        for item in permutations(letters, i):
            item = "".join(list(item))
            startLetter = list(item)[0]
            if check(item, startLetter):
                print("\n\n***Got one***\n", item)
                words.append(item)
    return words


vowels = ["a"]*15 + ["e"]*21 + ["i"]*13 + ["o"]*13+ ["u"]*5

consonants =  ["b"]*2 + ["c"]*3 + ["d"]*6 + ["f"]*2 + ["g"]*3 +["h"]*2 +["j"]*1 +["k"]*1 +["l"]*5 +["m"]*4 +["n"]*8 +["p"]*4 +["q"]*1 +["r"]*9 +["s"]*9 +["t"]*9 + ["v"]*1 +["w"]*1 +["x"]*1 +["y"]*1 +["z"]*1

print("***Let's play a letters game!***")

sleep(3)

letters = generateLetters()

sleep(uniform(1, 1.5))

print("\n\n***Let's play countdown***\n\n\n\n\n")

print(letters)

for count in reversed(range(1, 31)):
    print(count)
    sleep(1)
print("\n\nStop!")

print("All possible words:")

print(possibleWords(letters, words))

'''

#Code for sorting the dictionary into files

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

alphabet = list(alphabet)

for letter in alphabet:

    allFile = open("Dictionary.txt", "r+")

    filename = letter + ".txt"

    letterFile = open(filename, "w")

    for line in allFile:
        if len(list(line.lower())) <= 9:
            if list(line.lower())[0] == letter:
                print("Writing:", line.lower())
                letterFile.write(line.lower())

    allFile.close()
    letterFile.close()
```

> I have 26 text files called a.txt, b.txt, c.txt... to make the search quicker

(Sorry it's not very neat - I haven't finished it yet)

However, instead of returning what I expect (pan), it returns all words with pan in it (pan, pancake, pans, pandemic...)

Is there any way in Python you can only return the line if it's EXACTLY the same as the string? Do I have to .read() the file first?

Thanks

Comment: check out `\b` in [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), And I suggest you post your code on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) once it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is strangely written so excuse me if I missmatch

> Is there any way in Python you can only return the line if it's EXACTLY the same as the string? Do I have to .read() the file first?

Yes, there is!!!

```
file = open("file.txt")
content = file.read() # which is a str
lines = content.split('\n') # which is a list (containing every lines)

test_string = " pan "
positive_match = [l for l in lines if test_string in l]
```

This is a bit hacky since we avoid getting pancake for pan (for instance) but using spaces (and then, what about cases like ".....,pan "?). You should have a look at tokenization function. As pythonists, we hve one of the best library for this: [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html)

(because, basically, you are reinventing the wheel)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - just to clarify, the text files are just words on every line that start with the text file name - although when I remove the spaces, it still has the error in it. Also, I want the code to return only 'pan' instead of pan, pancake, marzipan etc.

Comment: Rewrote the files with spaces either side and it works - Thanks